# How to open entire subnet with iptables

Tags: iptables, tcp, subnet

I want to enable the entire subnet 192.168.1.0/24 which is connected to eth0 in input. I'm very unfamiliar with iptables.

If I add the rule:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 45678 -j ACCEPT
```

it works on ONE port. But we want all ports open to our subnet (both tcp and udp), so I tried:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

But it fails (no error, we simply cannot connect). What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: The syntax is right (though that last line essentially turns the firewall off on that interface).  But with `iptables` rules, **order is important because first dispositive match wins**.  If you show us the *whole* of your ruleset, with `iptables -L -n -v`, we might be able to comment further.

Comment: Or you could just give us the output of `iptables-save`.

Comment: Just remove `-p tcp -m tcp --dport 45678`.  If you are doing this without saving to disk, then change `-A` to `-I` to insert the rule at the top.

Comment: Ha, OK, I though it was the last rule that won. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just allow the whole subnet without further qualification

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT.
```

Note the use of `-I` rather than `-A`.